# Custom spinner UI with arrow and vertical line

Tags: android, spinner

I am trying to implement a spinner with a custom layout (not the spinner item layout), the outer layout. I want it to look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1uIK.jpg

I searched stackoverflow and google, but couldn't figure out how to come up with this (beside putting the whole picture as a background)

Thanks a lot in advance

**Edit**
This is what I tried:

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="spinner">
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_bg</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
</style>
```

**spinner_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="#ff0000"
                        android:startColor="#ff0000" android:type="linear" />
                    <stroke android:width="0.33dp" android:color="#0fb1fa" />
                    <corners android:radius="0dp" />    
                    <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:right="5dp">
                <bitmap android:gravity="center_vertical|right" android:src="@drawable/arrow_white_down" />
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

where `arrow_white_down` is a png of a tiny white arrow (like the one in the link)

Comment: Please describe what have you tried so far.

Comment: Why my question got downvoted? I really couldn't find a related stackoverflow question and dont know where to start! The best I could do is set the whole picture in above link as background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using a RelativeLayout with the spinner and an image (arrow) beside it, it doesn't look really good in `spinnerMode="dropdown"` but this is the best I could do

**layout**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/spinner_container"
    style="@style/spinner_container">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        style="@style/spinner"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/spinner_image"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/spinner_image" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/spinner_image"
        style="@style/spinner_image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="spinner_container">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">35dp</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>

    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">0dp</item>

    <item name="android:background">@color/red</item>
</style>

<style name="spinner">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>

    <item name="android:layout_margin">0dp</item>

    <item name="android:layout_alignParentLeft">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentStart">true</item>

    <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>

    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/red</item>

    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
</style>

<style name="spinner_image">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>

    <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>

    <item name="android:layout_alignParentRight">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentEnd">true</item>
    <item name="android:adjustViewBounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/bc_spinner_arrow</item>
</style>
```

where `bc_spinner_arrow` is a transparent pic of a white arrow and a vertical line (like the one in the question)